# How do i get rid of undefined in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom, setinterval

I am a self taught newbie at programming and I'm trying to play around with arrays, DOM and setInterval() method. I wrote a code that accesses the h1 tag of my html file and displays each element of an array at 1000 millisecond intervals in that tag. Unfortunately, the code runs successfully but displays "undefined" at the end of the execution. When I check the elements section of the Chrome Dev Tools, I realize that my h1 tag keeps blinking which I assume stipulates that my code keeps running even after all the elements in the array have been extinguished. I have used the filter method, clearTimeout() method and still get the same results. I will paste my code below. Hopefully I get a solution to my issue. Appreciate the feedback in advance!

```js
function myFunction() {
  const welcome = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "Is", "Philip", "Nice", "To", "Meet", "You!"];

  for (let i = 0; i < welcome.length; i++) {
    function subset() {
      document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = welcome[i++];
    }
    setInterval(subset, 1000);
    return;
  }
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<h1 id="heading"></h1>
```

Comment: Why would you use `clearTimeout()` for an *interval*? Try [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)... however the way you've architected your loop here doesn't seem to align with what you *expect* to happen. I would recommend following the logic here and trying explaining, in plain English, what you expect to happen in each iteration here.

Comment: For me it looks like you should replace [i++] with just [i] and then i++; in the next row. Or "i += 1";

Comment: I expect the h1 tag to display each element of my array at 1 second intervals. It executes correctly but includes an undefined at the end. My issue is to know why undefined is included in the list of array items and a possible solution to this problem

Comment: Here's a tip, add the console.log into subset `function subset() { console.log('test');`. You should see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

You could reorganize this so that each function call sets up the next function call. This way you don't need to worry about keeping track of intervals to clear and it's easier to understand how i is being incremented. If you're not clear on how function.bind() works I recommend reading up on that, it's pretty useful.

```
function myFunction(i) {
const welcome = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "Is", "Philip", "Nice", "To", "Meet", "You!"];
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = welcome[i];
if (i < welcome.length - 1)
    setTimeout(myFunction.bind(null, i + 1), 1000);
```

}
myFunction(0);

Answer (score 0):

You might find `setTimeout` easier to manage. Here we call a function with the array, initialise the index, and then call an inner function.

This logs each word of the array. We increment the index, and then, if the index is less than the array length, we call the `loop` function again.

```js
// Declare your array, and cache your element
const welcome = ['Hello', 'My', 'Name', 'Is', 'Philip', 'Nice', 'To', 'Meet', 'You!'];
const heading = document.getElementById('heading');

function myFunction(arr) {

  // Initialise the index
  let index = 0;

  // `setTimeout` calls `loop` if the
  // index < than the array length
  function loop() {

    const el = arr[index];

    // Add the word to the heading
    // Depending on the index prefix a space to it
    const word = index ? ` ${el}`: el;
    heading.textContent += word;

    // Increment the index
    ++index;

    // If the index < than the array length
    // call the `loop` function again
    if (index < arr.length) {
      setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
  
  }
  
  // Call `loop` for the first time
  loop();

}

// Call `myFunction` with the array
// as an argument
myFunction(welcome);
```

```html
<h1 id="heading"></h1>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you use `setinterval` which is endlessly running every 1000s unless you reset it or an error stops it - it's not bound to your loop.
This comes quite near to what you did:

```
    let cnt = 0;
    const welcome = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "Is", "Philip", "Nice", "To", "Meet", "You!"];
    const headingTag = document.getElementById("heading");

    function headingLoop() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            headingTag.innerHTML = welcome[cnt];
            cnt += 1;
            if (cnt < welcome.length) {
                headingLoop();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    headingLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

In sticking with your current `setInterval()` approach, you could do something like this.

This approach eliminates the need for the loop. Because `setInterval()` is calling the function repeatedly, it is taking care of that.

```
// set array
const welcome = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "Is", "Philip", "Nice", "To", "Meet", "You!"];

// declare index tracking variable and set to 0
let i = 0;

// declare your setInterval function and assign to myInterval so you can clear later
const myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

// declare the function that setInterval() will call to output the array to the document
function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = welcome[i];
  i++;

  // clear interval when you've reached the end of the array
  if(i > welcome.length - 1) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan. This approach helped me. It's amazing to know there is a community of like minded people who can help me on this journey!!!

Comment: Happy to help out and best of luck to you.